# How can I see when edit ban began?

Tags: support, edit-ban

I noticed recently that when I tried to make an edit, I got a message saying one other reviewer needed to approve it.  I'm unsure when that started, or what prompted it.  I can see that I've had a few edits rejected, but am unsure how to see when and how this limitation will be lifted.  As I type this question I see nothing similar in "Questions that may already have your answer" but it's hard to believe I'm the only one to ask.

And now I get this weird thing... after editing a question from Help & Improvement is says I edited it minutes ago but nothing new is coming up:  the only link that's active is "cancel".

[image]

Comment: You...um...that could not have happened. You have well over 3k rep, so you have full editing privileges. Those cannot be revoked by anything less than a suspension. Can you maybe describe in more detail what you saw? Or better yet, provide a screenshot?

Comment: That doesn't sound like you are edit banned.  It sounds like you reviewed a suggested edit on a post and was told it still needs one more review to be published

Comment: @CodyGray Let me see if I can reproduce the thing I saw.  Just a moment.

Comment: Was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17005026) the edit?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I believe that's the one I'm asking about.

Comment: OK.  This just sounds like normal behavior then.  When you go to a question that has a pending suggested edit link and you click edit instead of editing the post you get a review page.  You can approve it, reject it, accept and edit or reject and edit.  If you just click approve and your the first one it will tell you that there is X reviews still needed.  Right now that is 1 because it only needs 2 review but it used to be 3.

Comment: @NathanOliver Okay, I was just taken aback by the message that others need to review the edit, I suppose.  If that's normal behavior okay, sorry to have bothered you folks, thanks.

Comment: If I want to get a suggested edit out into production, I can usually find a (genuine) change that will improve it, so I use "Accept and Edit" to make the change.  That was more of an issue when it took three reviews to approve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question in the title: edit bans are [7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337/295232) in length and the reason shown looks like:

> Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 5 days.

That would mean your edit ban began ~2 days ago.

---

But, as it turned out from the discussion, you are not edit banned at all; that would be quite hard with >2k reputation, but it's still possible if you have too many tag wiki edits rejected.

Comment: Do you mean "2 days ± 12 hours ago"? "±2 days ago" doesn't make very much sense.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 probably a Dutch habit, where 'plusminus' means 'about'.

Comment: I did try to improve (rather empty) wiki-tags, but my reviewers did not like them and now I am banned with the error message "Too many of your edits were rejected." (without the "try again"). Is that a permanent ban? Any way out of it?

Comment: @B--rian no, it's the same length for tag wikis and normal posts: 7 days.